# Need to use resilience4j retry and circuitbreaker in spring boot 1.3.0 Release

Tags: spring-boot, resilience4j

I have a existing spring boot project developed in Spring boot 1.3.0 RELEASE. I want to use resilience4j retry and circuitbreaker functionality.
I find resilience4j used in spring boot 2.0+ versions mostly.
Can I use resilience4j with Spring boot 1.3.0 release version and go into production as there is less support for spring boot legacy versions I feel correct me if I am wrong?
Any guide if I can accommodate resilience4j in spring boot 1.3.0 release for retry and circuitbreaker will help.

Note: It's not possible to upgrade Spring boot version which is 1.3.0 Release in this case
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```